# I would like to get useful link at the end with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, call, attr

At the end would like to get this: mondaysoupcall.html and call into another div.

This is the target div:
`<div class="description"></div>`

This is the label where I want to click and read "data-id" <--(I dont know why this is my idea) I'm newbie
`<label for="sel1" id="mondaysoupcall" data-id="mondaysoupcall">Soup</label>`

and this is my part of the jquery code. I can get attributes easily but calling back or convert to text is quiet difficult to me. (I am still newbie).

```
var dab = $(this).attr('data-id');
$('label').click(function(){
    alert( $(this).attr('dataid'));
    $(".description").load(dab+'.html');
});
```

The alert window is comes up if i click on the label. And the consol log says:
 http://localhost/wichkitchen/undefined.html 404 (Not Found). Undefined because of my variable is still attrinbute not text.
So somewhat I would like to call in the little html into the "description" div. The name should be in the label tag, no anchor. Any solution I am interested in jquery. Thank you guys.

[console log about link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WhEV.jpg)
[allert window calling attribute.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A67t1.jpg)

Comment: Where is dab defined? I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: Put `dab` in your click function. It's outside.

Comment: Jeremy Styers -> in the fist line call back data-id as attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are calling your data attribute wrong.

```
$('label').on('click', (e) => {
    let dataId = $(this).attr('data-id') + '.html';
    // alternative let dataId = $(this).data('id') + '.html';
    $('.description').load(dataId, () => {
        alert('Data loaded!');
    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you but it's still doesn't work. Cal back back data-id it's still do not added to the link. Still undefined.